# How to apply impulse to the node on touch angle

Tags: swift, touch, skphysicsbody

I want the node to move in the right direction but the impulse to be with set strength.

```
let node: SKSpriteNode!;

node = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake(50, 50));
node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: node.size);
node.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false;
node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false;

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    node.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);   

    // ver 1     
    node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake((0.4) * (location.x - node.position.x), (0.4) * (location.y - node.position.y)), atPoint: CGPointMake(position.x,position.y));

    // ver 2
    let offset:CGPoint = self.vecSub(location, b: ghost.position);
    let direction: CGPoint = self.vecNormalize(offset);
    var len: CGPoint = self.vecMult(direction, b: 40);
    let impulseVector:CGVector = CGVectorMake(len.x, len.y);
    ghost.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulseVector);

}

func vecAdd(a: CGPoint, b:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPointMake(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}

func vecSub(a: CGPoint, b:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPointMake(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
}

func vecMult(a: CGPoint, b:CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPointMake(a.x * b, a.y * b);
}

func vecLenght(a:CGPoint)->CGFloat{
    return CGFloat( sqrtf( CFloat(a.x) * CFloat(a.x) + CFloat(a.y) * CFloat(a.y)));
}

func vecNormalize(a:CGPoint)->CGPoint{
    let len : CGFloat = self.vecLenght(a);
    return CGPointMake(a.x / len, a.y / len);
}
```

- version 1 is horrible
- version 2 is okay, but is too expensive
- version 3: something not expensive and to apply impulse with 15-100 strength, because if the touch is at the edges of the screen the node should move only 15-100 of its current possition without reaching the touch position

Answer (score 0):

Both the methods you've detailed above work so I'm not exactly sure what you're problem is. Also, I'm not sure method two is it's too expensive, are you having frame rate drops using it?

But I've got another way you could do what you're after, it's basically the second version but cleaned up. But firstly I just wanted to point out a couple things with your current code:

**1.** You don't need to `;` to the end of each line.

**2.** Instead of using `vecAdd`, `vecSub` etc you could overload the `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` operators which would make your code cleaner and clearer. This way, the operators would also be global so you could use them anywhere else you need to manipulate vectors.

Anyway, here's my attempt at it:

**Firstly,** extend `CGVector` to add the functionality you need. Things like `length`, which you were defining as functions, could be properties of `CGVector`:

```
extension CGVector {
    init(p1: CGPoint, p2: CGPoint) {
        self.dx = p1.x - p2.x
        self.dy = p1.y - p2.y
    }

    var length: CGFloat {
        get { return hypot(dx, dy) }

        set {
            normalise()
            dx *= newValue
            dy *= newValue
        }
    }

    mutating func normalise() {
        dx /= length
        dy /= length
    }
}
```

**Secondly,** using the new methods:

```
var vec = CGVector(p1: location, p2: ghost.position)
vec.length = 40
ghost.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(vec)
```

Alternatively, if you wanted the size of the impulse to relate to how far away from the ghost the user pressed, use the following:

```
vec.length *= 0.1
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes with method two there is frame rate decrease, i will try your code and hopefully is working, thanks you very much

Comment: That's strange, I tried method two and there didn't seem to be any more of a drop in fps than normal when using the simulator. Did you try testing on a device when using method two?

Comment: I have iPhone 5s and at the begin it drops to 57-58 fps and there is lag in movement of the node.

Comment: Hummm, I'd use Instruments if I was you to track down the exact cause of why it's taking so long on each frame.

Comment: This only rotates my ball, doesnt impulse it on the correct angles, how can i make it work? im trying to impulse a ball and depending on the location you touched the SKSpriteNode, impulse it that direction (opposite of the touched location) and based on how far of the center you are of the Sprite, it would determine the strength of impulse.