# How can i calculate the reflection of a coordinate in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, math

Alike the common math axis where the origin (0,0) is in the center of the axis, the origin in Swift (Using Sprite Kit) is in bottom-left if i'm not mistaken.

So, I need to calculate the complete opposite x,y on a sprite that i touched on, but i can't find a way yet, i'm not very good at math.

In a normal axis, it would be as easy as giving the coordinate A (-7,8), the number I would be looking for is (7,-8). But how can I get the same with a non-zero axis? Where there all positive values.

To demonstrate a little bit better, I just made this picture:

[image]

The outer frame boundaries would be my phone screen, that would be my real origin 0,0 right?

Now, imagine that I just tapped on the coordinate (13,13) of that box. The height and width of the box is 12px by 12px.
The origin of the box at that point is (10,10).

The point I would like to get is the (19,19). How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All are basic math.

First. find the center point:

`centerPoint = (sprite.origin.x + sprite.width/2, sprite.origin.y + sprite.height/2)`

Second. find the reflection point:

suppose you touch `touchPoint`

then:

`reflectPoint = (2 * centerPoint.x - touchePoint.x, 2 * centerPoint.y - touchePoint.y)`

Comment: thanks for the reply. Do you know if my touch point would be touch.locationInNode(self) ? i got a let location = touch.locationInNode(self). But that location.x and location.y doesnt look like its the correct touch location. Because for example, i think is not right that the location.x being smaller than the sprite.position.x

Comment: Btw,  by applying what you told me, it works but only for one side, should this math also work for the right side? If i touch left, it should give me the top-right coordinate, if i touch right it should give me the top-left point.

Comment: Sure it works for both side. About the location, if self means the SKScene, then it's correct, if self means the sprite it self, then you need to make some extra change.

Comment: Yea, i get the location from self inside touchesBegan function. So it should be the Scene.

Comment: sprite.position.x and sprite.position.y would be the sprite's origin, right? the "0,0" of the sprite starting from the bottom-left side. Am I correct? Thanks

Comment: @msqar Yes. it should mean the origin,

Comment: Ty, i will take a look then, and let you know :) thanks for all the tips and your time

Comment: mmm looks im not having success, maybe i'm not approaching it correctly :/ this is the first post i made, the main issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998343/impulse-skspritenode-depending-on-touched-location-swift-2 not having luck at all trying to make that work. Do you know if the approach is correct? or would you do something different?

Comment: Looks like in Swift 2, the sprite location is already in the center. So sprite.position,x and sprite.position.y is in its center