# How do i get the real center of a SKSpriteNode in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to figure out the center of my Sprite, i used a soccer ball sprite, changed size to be 120 by 120.
I managed to get the touch location.

The way to get the center should be sprite.origin.x + (sprite.width / 2), but for some reason, the value i'm getting is non sense. Because no matter where i touch the ball, the touch location.x is always smaller than the Sprite center, even though for example I touched on the right side of the ball, so that way location.x should be > than sprite.center.x.

This is the little code to get ball's center point

```
let ballCenter = CGVectorMake(ball.position.x + (ball.frame.width / 2),
                              ball.position.y + (ball.frame.height / 2))
```

But when I print the results like this, is always going to the "true" case.

```
 if location.x < ballCenter.dx {
     print("touched on left of ball ", location.x, location.y)
 }else{
     print("touched on right of ball ", location.x, location.y)   
 }
```

This is driving me crazy, can anyone help me to understand this? The sprite origin isn't in the bottom-left?

Also, why the scene frame is so small? I see that my screen Width is 375.0 and screen Height is 667.0 when i'm using an iPhone 6S, shouldn't it be bigger? This is so confusing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A SpriteNode's origin is in the center of the sprite by default. If you want to get the center of the node, just use `let ballCenter = sprite.position` - this will give you a CGPoint to work with. You can then access the x and y coordinates by using `ballCenter.x` and `ballCenter.y`.

Also, if you're wanting to create a point like you're currently doing with `ballCenter`, use `CGPointMake()` instead of `CGVectorMake()`.

Comment: Can you see if you can help me to achieve this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998343/impulse-skspritenode-depending-on-touched-location-swift-2 it's driving me nuts haha attempted already so many things and i still couldn't come up with a nice way on doing it